# Implementing menu in the middle of a web page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm implementing a menu in the middle of a web page (note: this is not a top navigation menu).

So this is the default state:
[image]

And people can click on other menu items to view different content.
[image]

I  tried writing the following code for one menu item and it is working... but is there an elegant solution that works for every menu item?

```
<script> 
    $(function() {
      $("#menu3").click(function(){
          $(this).css({
            'text-decoration':'underline',
            'font-family':'Gotham-Medium'
          });
          $("#content1").hide();
          $("#content3").show();          
      });
    }); 
</script>


  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><div id="menu1">menu1</div></li>
      <li><div id="menu2">menu2</div></li>
      <li><div id="menu3">menu3</div></li>
      <li><div id="menu4">menu4</div></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Also, I wrote the following code for menu item hover state. Very strangely, things work with this code:

```
<script> 
    $(function() {
      $("#menu3").mouseenter(function(){
          $(this).css({
            'text-decoration':'underline',
            'font-family':'Gotham-Medium'
          }); 
      });
    }); 
</script>
```

BUT once I add the mouseleave code.... things stop working (including mouseenter enter state, so nothing happens when you hover over menu). Not sure what's going on or how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

```
<script> 
    $(function() {
      $("#menu3").mouseenter(function(){
          $(this).css({
            'text-decoration':'underline',
            'font-family':'Gotham-Medium'
          }); 
      $("#menu3").mouseleave(function(){
          $(this).css({
            'text-decoration':'none',
            'font-family':'Gotham-Medium'
          }); 
      });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your hover state, please use CSS. With CSS I mean using `:hover` selector. You should add a class on all the menu buttons and then target them. Example:

// HTML

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><div class="menu-item" id="menu1">menu1</div></li>
      <li><div class="menu-item" id="menu2">menu2</div></li>
      <li><div class="menu-item" id="menu3">menu3</div></li>
      <li><div class="menu-item" id="menu4">menu4</div></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

// CSS

```
.menu-item:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And for showing content on click, you should use the same approach which you are using for adding css with jQuery i.e. by using `this`.
Since we have added a class on menu buttons, we can use that to add our event listener and then we can also add a class on all menu content and hide them all together. By keeping a pattern between menu button id and content id, we can have a generic solution.

```
$(".menu-item").click(function(){
    $(".menu-content").hide();
    $('#'+$(this).attr('id') + '-content').show();          
});
```

See working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/etqwf3kr/

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks. hover state worked too, but I've added active state code after hover (see below) - hover state is still working but active state is NOT working. What am I doing wrong? 
 .menu-item:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Gotham-Medium';
}

 .menu-item:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: 'Gotham-Medium';
}

Comment: There is no difference in the style of your hover and active state, that why you feel that active state is not working.

Comment: No - in active state, it goes back to normal state, not hover state.  Hover state has text underlined and normal state isn't underlined. What could be causing this error?

Comment: What do you expect from you active state?

Comment: exactly the same as hover state, underlined & font family set as Medium.

Comment: That is exactly what is happening. Which browser you are using?

Comment: Just to clarify, active state targets an element between the time it is clicked on and the time it is released.

Comment: oh - i thought it's for the clicked state. how do i style for the clicked state? i.e. when i'm checking out menu content for menu 3, for example. I'm using chrome

Comment: This should help you: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: Try to do it in your project because :visited state is not working on jsfiddle

Comment: Ended up using a bit of jquery (b/c :focus didn't work) but this was hugely helpful thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/kdvy60Lu/). And few things that you should know;

**HTML**

It is better if you have an [ID](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) for the menu. Because the class name `menu` is common and you may easily face styling issues as you build your website. Also it's not necessary to have a div inside the list (`<li>...</li>`). (If required an [anchor tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) (`<a>...</a>`) would be a better option than a `div`.) You can simplfy it like this.

```
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
          <li>MENU 1</li>
          <li>MENU 2</li>
          <li>MENU 3</li>
          <li>MENU 4</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**CSS**

You dont need to use jQuery to implement the `hover` styles. You can do it efficiently using css. Like this.

```
    #menu li {
      font-family: 'Gotham-Medium';
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #menu li:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

**jQuery**

You don't have to write your code for each nav element. You can use the class to hide and show only what was clicked. Like this.

```
      $("#menu li").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#menu li").hide();
        $(this).show();
      });
```

Comment: I was looking to have content for menu item show (not the menu item itself), but appreciate your help